# Read Jinja file in Python

Tags: python, jinja2

I have to read `Jinja` file and I have to get particular attribute from file.
Consider below example: 
I have `demo.jinja` file containing :

```
resources:
- name: a-new-network
  type: compute.v1.network
  properties:
    IPv4Range: 10.0.0.1/16
```

I have to fetch the value of `type` attribute i.e `compute.v1.network`.

I tried:
Considered above code as `yaml`. And tried:

```
a = """resources:
- name: a-new-network
  type: compute.v1.network
  properties:
    IPv4Range: 10.0.0.1/16"""

print yaml.load(a)
```

which is printing `{'resources': [{'type': 'compute.v1.network', 'name': 'a-new-network', 'properties': {'IPv4Range': '10.0.0.1/16'}}]}`

So from this, I can get `type` easily: `["resources"][0]["type"]`

This is working as expected for above `.jinja` file.

I have another jinja format too which is containing `{%  --- %}` like code.

```
{% for i in range(properties['readReplicas']) %}
- name: {{ ID }}-rr-{{ i }}
  type: sqladmin.v1beta4.instance
  properties:
    backendType: SECOND_GEN
    instanceType: READ_REPLICA_INSTANCE
    databaseVersion: {{ properties['cloudsql']['databaseVersion'] }}
    region: {{ properties['cloudsql']['region'] }}
    masterInstanceName: $(ref.{{ ID }}-master.name)
    replicaConfiguration:
      failoverTarget: false
    settings:
      tier: {{ properties['cloudsql']['tier'] }}
  {% if properties['failover'] %}
  metadata:
    dependsOn:
      - {{ ID }}-failover
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I get value of `type` i.e `sqladmin.v1beta4.instance` in this case? Because for above `jinja` content, I can not consider it as `yaml`.

Comment: Can you just use regex?

Comment: @knh190 : Type attribute may come in `properties` or anywhere. Multiple `type`  variable may also there. So I can't use regex in that case.

Comment: @knh190 Do you know anything like predefined `jinja2` package to solve above problem?

Comment: There's a `Environment.parse` in jinja returns AST of a template. But I haven't tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried and it worked:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import yaml

config_src = yaml.load(open("./demo1.yaml"))
config_data = config_src["resources"][0]
env = Environment(loader = FileSystemLoader("./"), trim_blocks=True, lstrip_blocks=True)
template = env.get_template("./demo1.jinja")
data = template.render(config_data)
sdata = yaml.load(data)
print(sdata["resources"][0]["type"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Jinja is a template language, so you can eliminate its variables by feeding it data. The data to feed is case by case. In your example, the file format is yaml after rendering. So you can craft a data file `demo.yaml` like this:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "readReplicas": 1,
        "cloudsql": {
            "databaseVersion": 0,
            "region": 0,
            "tier": 0,
            "failover": 0
        }
    },
    "ID": 0
}
```

Then render your template with the data file, for example, using [jinja-cli](https://github.com/cykerway/jinja-cli):

```
jinja -d demo.yaml -f yaml demo.jinja | python3 -c "import sys,yaml;print(yaml.load(sys.stdin.read())[0]['type']);"
```

Output:

```
sqladmin.v1beta4.instance
```

Comment: It means, first I have to convert jinja content into yaml. But the question is, how to convert jinja to yaml programatically. (specially jinja containing {% for} {% endfor %} etc )

Comment: @HarshaB I'm not aware of a jinja parser usable in shell. If you know one you could paste it here. But I still question that could solve your problem here because Jinja templates can be rendered into anything, it's *yaml* in your example. Ultimately you are parsing *yaml*, so just eliminate the Jinja variables.

Comment: @HarshaB You convert jinja to yaml by rendering it with data. This is usually simpler than using a Jinja template parser. But you are free to try either.

Comment: Can you please tell how to convert jinja to yaml which containing containing {% for} {% endfor %} etc?

Comment: @HarshaB Just run the command line as I wrote them. Jinja for loop will be resolved during rendering and they won't show up in the rendered yaml.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the solution(1 upvote for the solution). But biggest challenge is to create demo.json from jinja file programatically.

Comment: I am having jinja + yaml. So is it possible to create json from these 2 file?

Comment: @HarshaB Nope... The json file is specially crafted so that the rendered output will be in a format that is easy to parse. `jinja` is the tool to render. `yaml` is the tool to parse result. Neither is a tool to write the json data file. It's your data. You should know how to write a data file.

Comment: Ok. I was not talking about jinja + yaml tool. I was talking about .jinja and .yaml files. You have added values as 0 in JSON for all variables (accept for loop variable.) But I am having .yaml file which containing these values. So was asking from those files can I create JSON and so your answer will help afterwards.

Comment: @HarshaB Check updated answer. I changed json to yaml if you feed data via yaml files. You don't need to create json. Just add `-f yaml`.